# C++ Поиск слова в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте, есть код определяющий модель чипа видеокарты в данном случае моя карта - это `NVIDIA Gefore GTX 970` как мне из модели чипа вытащить только производителя чипа. Было так `NVIDIA Gefore GTX 970` должно получиться так `NVIDIA`, ни один метод из интернета мне не помог.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define _WIN32_DCOM
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));

    DISPLAY_DEVICEW dd;
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osv;

    osv.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXW);
    GetVersionExW((LPOSVERSIONINFO)&osv);
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICEW);
    EnumDisplayDevicesW(NULL, 0, &dd, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME);


    wcout << L"video: " << dd.DeviceString << endl;
    wcout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поиск первого пробела и получение подстроки ровно до него

Comment: Полистал, куча примеров http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread756908.html

Comment: На C я бы просто первый пробел заменил на 0, in place.

Answer (score 3):

Ну если предполагается, что первое слово в полном названии - это производитель чипа, то можно, например, так.

```
string Device = "NVIDIA Gefore GTX 970";
cout << Device.substr(0, Device.find(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не известно правило по которому можно вычленить имя производителя из названия видеокарты, то можно сделать так.

Напишем функтор для проверки есть ли в строке подстрока:

```
struct Contains{
    std::string str;
    explicit Contains(const std::string &str):
        str(str)
    {}
    bool operator()(const std::string &substr) const{
        return std::search(str.begin(), str.end(), substr.begin(), substr.end()) != str.end();
    }
};
```

Теперь можно попробовать найти в заданной строке одно из известных нам названий:

```
std::string company(const std::string &name){
    typedef std::vector<std::string> Companies;
    typedef Companies::const_iterator Company;

    static const Companies companies = {
        "RADEON",
        "NVIDIA",
        "OTHER"
    };

    Company company = std::find_if(companies.begin(), companies.end(), Contains(name));

    if(company == companies.end()){
        return "unknown";
    }

    return *company;
}
```

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/9iz4u)

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать один костыльный способ: просто вырезать все до первого пробела.